# How to draw rectangles on a binary image?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to draw rectangles on a binary image using `PIL.ImageDraw`. This is, what I have so far:

```py
npim = f #binary src image (np array)
plt.imshow(npim)

plt.imshow(np.array(npim))
pp = Image.fromarray(npim,'1') #PIL object to draw on

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.array(pp))

ix = ImageDraw.Draw(pp)
ix.rectangle([(0,0),(100,100)],outline=1) #draw rectangle of 1's on the image

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.array(pp))
```

The result of those three plots:

[image: This]

How can I draw rectangles using `PIL.ImageDraw` on this binary image while preserving the image underneath it? It seems that when I convert the array back to an `Image` object that the image is not preserved.

Conversions to RGB and grayscale similarly fail, they may show the rectangle but no image in the background.

EDIT: Here is the original image, not the Matplotlib plots.

[image: Original]

Comment: Please show your actual input and output images rather than matplotlib impressions of them with borders and tickmarks. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have included the original input image

Answer (score 1):

The pitfall here is the usage of [image mode `1`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes):

```py
pp = Image.fromarray(npim, '1')
```

Your input image is not a real "binary image", but rather an usual 8-bit grayscale image. So, just stick to the corresponding [image mode `L`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-mode) and you get the expected output:

```py
pp = Image.fromarray(npim, 'L')
```

Actually, if `npim` is already stored as a single channel `uint8` array, you can leave out the image mode entirely, and it still works:

```py
pp = Image.fromarray(npim)
```

For some thoughts on image mode `1`, maybe also have a look at [this earlier answer from me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59676321/11089932).